# Local Storage of table into array

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hello and thanks in advance for your help! As a little background, I'm fairly new to the field (as will be obvious by my question) and I'm currently training to move into the department at my company. The first training project they gave me was to create a single page phonebook app that allows you to enter a name/number, add it to a list, delete rows from that list, and store the list in local storage. The other rule is that all HTML/CSS/Javascript has to be contained in one file (I'm assuming this is teaching me a lesson about splitting up the different parts into multiple files is a good idea).

Now the issue I have is that i can create the phonebook entries, which I've added as new rows to an existing table, but can't seem to get them into local storage. This is my first venture into any kind of storage, so I'm struggling and would like a little guidance on where to go next or what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>Phonebook 1.0</title>

<style>
#welcome {
        background-color: #0000DD;
        border-radius: 5px;
        height: 50px;
}

#welcomeText {
        position: relative;
        left: 10px;
        top: 32%;
        color: white;
        font-family: Georgia, Verdana;
}

.header {
        font-family: Georgia, Verdana;
        font-size: 18px;

}

h1 {
        font-family: Georgia, Verdana;
}

#deleteRow {
        background-color: transparent;
        text-decoration: underline;
        border: none;
        color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
}



</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function contact (name, home, work, cell) {
        this.name = name;
        this.home = home;
        this.work = work;
        this.cell = cell;
    }

    var store = [];
    localStorage["store"] = JSON.stringify(store);

    function addRow() {

        var newContact = new contact(document.getElementById("name").value, document.getElementById("home").value, 
                                 document.getElementById("work").value, document.getElementById("cell").value);

        var table = document.getElementById("input");
        var row = table.insertRow(document.getElementById("input").rows.length);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

        cell1.innerHTML = newContact.name;
        cell2.innerHTML = newContact.home;
        cell3.innerHTML = newContact.work;
        cell4.innerHTML = newContact.cell;
        cell5.innerHTML = "<button id='deleteRow'>Delete</button>"

        for (i = 2; i < document.getElementById("input").rows.length; i++) {
            store.push(table[i]);
        };

        console.log(storedData);
        console.log(store);
    }

    var storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage["names"]);



</script>       
</head>

<body>

<h1>Phonebook Beta 1.7</h1>

<div id="welcome">
    <b id="welcomeText">Welcome to my single-page phone book application.</b>
</div>

<table id="input">
    <tr>
        <th class="header"><b>Name</b></th>
        <th class="header"><b>Home</b></th>
        <th class="header"><b>Work</b></th>
        <th class="header"><b>Cell</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="name" type="text" name="name"></form></td>
        <td><input id="home" type="text" name="home"></form></td>
        <td><input id="work" type="text" name="work"></form></td>
        <td><input id="cell" type="text" name="cell"></form></td>
        <td><button onclick="addRow()">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to add an item into local storage would be

```
localStorage.setItem("store",JSON.stringify(store));
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

After store has been set.  Currently right now you are doing
    localStorage["store"] = JSON.stringify(store);

Which is a) incorrect and b) storing a null or empty array.

Try

```
for (i = 2; i < document.getElementById("input").rows.length; i++) {
        store.push(table[i]);
    };
 localStorage.setItem("store",JSON.stringify(store));
```

Comment: Ah okay this makes sense. It looks like it's creating a local storage array, but the values are all null. How does it know to store the value?

Comment: What does store output?